# How do I install local modules?

Tags: raku

For creating and maintaining Perl 5 modules, I use [`Dist::Zilla`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla). One of my favorite features is being able to install local modules.

However, with Perl 6, I'm not sure how to install local modules. Sure, I can use `use lib`:

```
use lib 'relative/path';
use My::Awesome::Module;
```

But, I'd really like to be able to install `My::Awesome::Module`, so that all I had to do was `use` it:

```
use My::Awesome::Module;
```

One way to accomplish this, would be setting [`PERL6LIB`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules.html#Finding_Modules), but that still isn't "installing" a module like `zef install ./My-Awesome-Module`.

---

Update: Looks like I need to craft an appropriate [META6.json](https://docs.perl6.org/language/modules#index-entry-META6.json-META6.json) file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To understand how to setup a module to be understood by toolchain utilities, see [Preparing the module](https://docs.raku.org/language/modules.html#Preparing_the_module). Typically this means adding a META6.json file that describes the distribution, including quasi-manifest elements such as which files you really meant to include/provide. Once the META6.json is created the module is ready to be installed:

```
zef install ./My-Awesome-Module
```

which (assuming no uninstalled dependencies) is essentially:

```
my $install-to-repo = CompUnit::RepositoryRegistry.repository-for-name("site");
my $preinstall-dist = Distribution::Path.new("./My-Awesome-Module");
$install-to-repo.install($preinstall-dist);
```

---

Starting with rakudo 2019.01 you can, assuming no uninstalled dependencies, install a local distribution *without* a META6.json -- but this is purely developmental nicety that won't work on complex setups that do not have e.g. namespacing and file structures that can be inferred.

```
my $read-from-repo   = CompUnit::Repository::FileSystem.new(prefix => "./My-Awesome-Module/lib");
my $install-to-repo  = CompUnit::RepositoryRegistry.repository-for-name("site");
my $some-module-name = "My::Awesome::Module"; # needed to get at the Distribution object in the next step
my $preinstall-dist  = $read-from-repo.candidates($some-module-name).head;
$install-to-repo.install($preinstall-dist);
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm writing a bin that may help you: http://github.com/FCO/6pm